# How to deploy docker-composed application with docker-machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

How to deploy docker-compose app with simple Rails application using docker-machine? And does it make sense?

I have read multiple articles on that topic, including [official Docker docs on using Compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) and [Remote Deployment Guide by Rackspace](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/dev-to-deploy-with-docker-machine-and-compose/), but none of it actually works for me.

I have a pretty simple Rails app described by the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: containers/production/Dockerfile
    image: projectname:app
    command: containers/production/bootstrap.sh
    ports:  
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gems:/gems
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DOCKERIZED=1

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data:
  gems:
```

Next I'm trying to deploy it to remote host using `docker-machine`:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env production)"
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

First two steps works perfectly well. Docker host attached to local Compose, `app` image built, `db` container started on production. But launching `app` failed:

```
Creating projectname_app_1 ...
Creating projectname_app_1 ... error

ERROR: for projectname_app_1  Cannot start service app: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"containers/production/bootstrap.sh\": stat containers/production/bootstrap.sh: no such file or directory"
```

Looks like I'm missing some important concepts about Machine. How I supposed to write production Compose files to make them work on remote containers host?

Answer (score 1):

from what I see in the error message, looks like your problem is that `containers/production/bootstrap.sh` doesn't exist **inside the docker instance**. the `command` executes a script inside the docker container, and not in the host machine.

Copy the script into the `workdir` of the container, and execute it with something like `./bootstrap.sh`, or maybe something like this could help too:

```
app:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: containers/production/Dockerfile
image: projectname:app
command: /bootstrap.sh
ports:  
  - 3000:3000
volumes:
  - .:/app
  - gems:/gems
  - ./containers/production/bootstrap.sh:/bootstrap.sh
depends_on:
  - db
environment:
  - DOCKERIZED=1
```

Check that I am matching a file on host with their respective path inside the container (`/bootstrap.sh`) and executing that in `command`

Comment: Good idea, thank you. Trying to implement your suggestions, but suddenly I start having `Cannot allocate memory` errors while building images on my DO droplet...

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? Maybe you can share some logs so we can help you.